# lxml.html parsing and utf-8 with requests

Tags: python, html, utf-8, web-scraping, lxml

i used requests to retrieve a url which contains some unicode characters, and want to do some processing with it , then write it out.

```
r=requests.get(url)
f=open('unicode_test_1.html','w');f.write(r.content);f.close()
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.content)
htmlOut = lxml.html.tostring(html)
f=open('unicode_test_2.html','w');f.write(htmlOut);f.close()
```

in unicode_test_1.html, all chars looks fine, but in unicode_test_2.html, some chars changed to gibberish, why is that ?

i then tried

```
html = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
htmlOut = lxml.html.tostring(html,encoding='latin1')
f=open('unicode_test_2.html','w');f.write(htmlOut);f.close()
```

it seems it's working now. but i don't know why is this happening, always use latin1 ?
what's the difference between r.text and r.content, and why can't i write html out using `encoding='utf-8'` ?

Answer (score 2):

You've not specified if you're using python 2 or 3. Encoding is handled quite differently depending on which version you're using.  The following advice is more or less universal anyway.

The difference between r.text and r.content is in the Requests docs. Simply put Requests will attempt to figure out the character encoding for you and return Unicode after decoding it. This which is accessible via r.text. To get just the bytes use r.content.

You really need to get to grips with encodings.  Read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html and watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sgHbC6udIqc to get started. Also, do a search for "Overcoming frustration: Correctly using unicode in python2" for additional help.

Just to clarify, it's not as simple as always use one encoding over another. Make a Unicode sandwich by doing any I/O in bytes and work with Unicode in your application. If you start with bytes (isinstance(mytext, str))  you need to know the encoding to decode to Unicode, if you start with Unicode (isinstance(mytext, unicode)) you should encode to UTF-8 as it will handle all the worlds characters.

Make sure your editor, files, server and database are configured to UTF-8 also otherwise you'll get more 'gibberish'.

If you want further help post the source files and output of your script.

Comment: The reading/video resources you recommended really cleared things up for me. Thanks.